# Get specific folder from a path string

Tags: c#, string, path, directory

Consider the path to a file like this:

"\\Tests\Results\knowles\project\LU\D15\RUN1\Results.xml"

How can I make a new string that gives the path to the "project" folder in the string above? I tried to use `FirstIndexOf("project")` but it always fails!

Is there a static method or something in `Directory` or `Path` class?

I want to have a new string which contains the path to the "project" folder, from similar strings like above example, something like

`var newPath = "\\\\Tests\\Results\\knowles\\project"`

Please note, the "project" folder is just an example, it can be any name, what I ment is that I want to get the path to the folder that suppose to be in place of the project in my example.

Again, my mistake I guess, the original string does not come always with fixed number of folders, it is for sure does have atleast one or two folders after the 'project' folder...I need a way to approach it from left to right I guess

Comment: Can you provide an example about what do you want to do?

Comment: By the way, what if the path would be `\\Tests\Results\knowles\project\project\project\project\LU\D15\RUN1\Results.xml`? Which path should be returned in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) class.

Do a right to left search as follows:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(""\\Tests\Results\knowles\project\LU\D15\RUN1\Results.xml"");
var di = fi.Directory;
var find = "project";

while (di.Name.ToLower() != find.ToLower() && di != null)
{
    di = di.Parent;
}

if (di == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Directory with name '{0}' was not found.", find));
}
```

Do a left to right search with a recursive solution. Something like this:
**NOTE** This is untested so may not be exactly right, but I think it's generally what you are trying to achieve.

```
var fi = new FileInfo(""\\Tests\Results\knowles\project\LU\D15\RUN1\Results.xml"");
var di = fi.Directory;
var find = "project";

di = GetGreatestParent(di, find);

if (di == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Directory with name '{0}' was not found.", find));
}

public DirectoryInfo GetGreatestParent(DirectoryInfo Dir, string Find)
{
    if (Dir != null)
    {
        var p = GetGreatestParent(Dir.Parent, string Find);

        if (p != null)
        {
            return p;
        }
        else if (Dir.Name.ToLower() == Find.ToLower())
        {
            return Dir;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, `project` is always different in my case, it can be `projectA` or anything else, I just interested in the folder that happens to be in that position. sorry if I didn't pointed this in my question.

Comment: @Sean87 Same applies, just change the logic to find the correct folder. For example, if you need a particular ancestor, use di.Parent.Parent.Parent ...

Comment: Again, my mistake I guess, the original string does not come always with fixed number of folders, it is for sure does have atleast one or two folders after the 'project' folder...I need a way to approach it from left to right I guess

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for this instance.

```
string path = @"\\Tests\Results\knowles\project\LU\D15\RUN1\Results.xml";
string folderToSearch = "project";
int index = path.IndexOf(folderToSearch);
if (index != -1)
  Console.WriteLine(path.Substring(0, index + folderToSearch.Length));
else
  Console.WriteLine("Folder not found in given string.");
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex:

```
var projectName = "project";
var inputString = @"\\Tests\Results\knowles\project\LU\D15\RUN1\Results.xml";

var yourProjectDir = Regex.Match(inputString, 
                                 String.Format(@"\\.+{0}\\", projectName),
                                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `Path` class , it has many helping methods , try to find one which suits your need.

You may try to use the following code to get the folder in the path, it will give you the last one.

```
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\\Abc\test.xml");
```

will give you `C:\\ABC` for example.